# Docker container not working when using "docker compose up", but works using "docker run" on "php8.0-apache" based image

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I have built a custom image for a php 8.0 site I need to deploy, I based on the official php8.0-apache image just as I have done previously with a similar php 7.3 one, however the apache server is not executing the php code on the site (it is displayed as text) when I start it with "docker compose up", however it works flawlessly if I use "docker run" on the same image.

Do I need to include something else on the image or the compose to make it work?

My Dockerfile:

```
FROM php:8.0-apache

#instalar pre-requesitos

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
        libbz2-dev \
        libzip-dev 

#instalar modulos pendentes
RUN docker-php-ext-install bcmath bz2 calendar exif gettext iconv mysqli opcache pdo_mysql shmop sockets sysvmsg sysvsem sysvshm zip

CMD ["apache2-foreground"]
```

######################

My docker compose:

```
version: "3.2"
services:
    php80vdev:
       image: php80vdev
       container_name: php80vdev
       restart: always
       #privileged: true
       volumes:
          #web-page
          - type: bind
            source: ./web
            target: /var/www/
          #config-apache
          - type: bind
            source: ./config
            target: /etc/apache2/conf-enabled/
       ports:
          - 46200:80
          #- 443:443
       networks:
          php80vdev-net:
             ipv4_address: 172.21.2.10
    db:
       image: mariadb
       container_name: php80vdev-db
       restart: always
       environment:
          MARIADB_ROOT_PASSWORD: MyDatabasePassword
       volumes:
          - type: bind
            source: ./db
            target: /var/lib/mysql
       ports:
          - 3306:3306
       networks:
          php80vdev-net:
             ipv4_address: 172.21.2.20
networks:
   php80vdev-net:
      driver: bridge
      ipam:
         driver: default
         config:
            - subnet: 172.21.2.0/24
```

I have an image built almost like this one (different apache modules), but based on the "php:7.3-apache" image and it is currently working without an issue, however the versions of Docker that is installed differs (20.10.16 on the production server where the php:7.3 container is currently running, and 24.0.5 on the "testing" server where I am currently testing the php:8.0 container)

I have tried removing the modules gradually thinking it was some kind of conflict / bug, but even with just the base image the error persisted if using the compose. As I have not found a similar issue when searching I decided to ask for assistance.

As there is quite some time since I last built an image I might be overlooking something that may be obvious to you.

I would appreciate any help offered

Comment: What exactly is not working? Seeing the logs might be useful. You could compare the logs of a `docker compose` from the working 7.3 version with the non-working newer version.

Comment: it does not execute the php code in the page as if it does not have php installed on it, simply displaying the code as plain text.
The apache container logs has no errors, or anything out of the ordinary, it is serving the pages as plain text as if it had no php installed.
And i did check the php version running docker exec on the running container and it gave the version as expected, without error, so it is installed

Comment: So it all starts up fine. That implies the problem is with the stuff in the image itself - the PHP install or more likely your custom code that runs in php7 has an issue with php8. I am not a php expert however I expect there is an error/info message somewhere in a log on the container or the stdout of the container that will point you in the right direction. It might be easier to try and debug the application locally (outside of docker) using a php8 runtime.